# Why do GNU Radio complex blocks (not custom) have different itemsizes?

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I am running GNU Radio 3.7.13.4 and working in GNU Radio Companion on Ubuntu 18.04

I have a very simple flowgraph where I have a source of type complex (I've tried both a signal source and a constant source) which I connect to a transcendental block (of type complex) and then output to a sink of type complex (I don't think anything after the transcendental block matters).

I have tried the transcendental block with functions "sin", "cos" and "exp". When I execute the flowgraph, I get the error:

```
ValueError: itemsize mismatch: sig_source_c0:0 using 8, transcendental0:0 using 16
```

The transcendental block is meant to take any cmath functions so I thought perhaps there were different function names for the complex and float cases? Something like "ccos" or csin" but I haven't seen any on the list of [available functions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/).

I have seen [similar questions](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/discuss-gnuradio/2014-03/msg00200.html) where people are creating custom blocks and OOT modules and seeing this problem. They have often used the wrong datatype (numpy complex 32 instead of 64).

I am not using any custom blocks. This problem is with stock/shipped GR blocks.

Any help is appreciated!